# Create a list of list from a flat list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know how to convert a list of list to a flat list. For example,

```
import itertools
list_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_))
print(merged)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is it possible other way around? in this case, for a given flat list, is it possible to make a list of list contains three elements?
I want to see the output like this

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

for a given input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `numpy`?

Answer (score 2):

Just take slices:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]

print(b)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Or if you actually want to use numpy as the tag implies, use `reshape()` as suggested above